# What do you call a customer at a government office?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say I walk into a Service Canada or a DMV or some other government office that serves people needing assistance with something. Am I a customer? A client? Neither of those seem right since I'm not paying, just using a public service. What's the word for this?

Sample sentence:
The helpful agent at the Service Canada assisted the ____ with her passport renewal.

Comment: If the person is there under their own free will for entertainment such as at a museum I would call them a visitor. If there’s some element of coercion such as at motor vehicles then maybe just a ‘person’. I just don’t see people waiting in line for hours at the DMV as customers—customers bring their custom to an establishment. One does not bring one’s custom to the DMV.

Comment: 'Punter' seems more hypernymic but less polite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you are right that neither *customer* nor *client* seems quite right (in that their 'home' seems to be in commercial settings), there has recently been a trend to use precisely these terms for this purpose, presumably in order to make people more comfortable with using such services. Between the two, *client* is probably better than *customer*, as the traditional notion of a client does not logically entail that a payment must be involved (one can be a client of a lawyer working *pro bono*).

If one does not wish to join this trend, one probably won't be able to find a general term that would cover everybody who is seeking or receiving some service from the government. One usually refers to such an individual by a specific term for the individual's status that is relevant to the transaction in question. In many cases, for example, the individual will be an **applicant** (for a passport, driver's licence and suchlike). In other cases, the individual may be referred to as a taxpayer, voter, driver, beneficiary, etc., depending on the nature of the government's service that is under discussion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sometimes I wish I could invent a word for these circumstances. Sigh.

Comment: There's also a political component: if you use a word like "citizen" then you're emphasizing that the state is providing a service for all citizens, which is good if you're a politician running it. "customer" has very different connotations of a business or commercial relationship, and can be used positively to emphasise to staff that they need to be nice to applicants, or if the government wants to restrict, privatise or impose a fee for a public service, it suggests you're not necessarily entitled to the service but will only get it if you pay.

Answer (score 2):

What does the DMV call them?

From the [Wisconsin DMV](https://wisconsindot.gov/Pages/online-srvcs/find-dmv/default.aspx):

> - ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​DMVs are open for all driver license and ID card **customers**. Driver licenses can be ​renewed online for most **customers**.

From the [California DMV](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv-research-reports/department-of-motor-vehicles-dmv-performance-reports/customers-eligible-to-renew-their-license-via-alternative-services-fiscal-year-2020-2021/):

> Over 1.6 million **customers** renewed their driver license in the first quarter of FY 2020-2021. Of those **customers**, over 900 thousand were eligible to renew via an alternative service channel. The chart below provides a breakdown of the method used by these eligible **customers** to renew their driver license. Field Office totals reflect those **customers** who chose to renew their driver license in a field office, even though they were eligible to renew using an alternative service channel.

From the [Colorado DMV](https://dmv.colorado.gov/dmv-experiencing-high-call-volume-leading-to-long-phone-waits-for-coloradans):

> Due to a large volume of calls being received by **customers** trying to schedule appointments, **customers** calling our Colorado Division of Motor Vehicles (DMV) call center have experienced a significant wait time and difficulty connecting to the phone queue.
>
> Phone scheduling was used to prioritize **customers** who had no choice but to use in-office services. In order to help alleviate wait times and **customer** frustration, the DMV has reopened online scheduling.

The clear preference is for **customer**, though I did see the domain specific term "driver" being used too.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your input. As a Canadian I'm not too familiar with DMVs though, do they offer any free services or do you always have to pay when you go?

Comment: The term is often used this way in official materials, but it is debatable whether that should be regarded as good English or bureaucratic jargon. The fact that a DMV's stylesheet requires its employees to use that term does not impose any obligation on those who don't work for the DMV to use it.

Comment: It looks like _the customer_'s always right.

Answer (score 1):

That is a great question, and your logic is perfect.  I can't think of an English word that means someone just wanting a public service.

In the US we would just use the word "customer", as it implies we don't work there and are needing help from someone who does.  "Client" (in the US) would refer more to a regular paying customer - like a man who has a lawyer on his payroll.

Comment: Sorry Chris, but this doesn't really answer my question. I'm looking for a better word than "customer". :)

Comment: @Raymo111 Why do you think there is one? He's just reporting the word that people use in this situation. Even people who ride the free city trolley or attend a free public art exhibit put on by the city government are still its customers, despite having paid nothing for the privilege.

Comment: @Raymo111: Certainly *customer* would be the most idiomatic choice, but you could try *patron*: [one who buys the goods or **uses the services** offered especially by an establishment](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patron).

Answer (score 0):

In your example citizen works.
According to the OED: A legally recognized subject or national of a state, commonwealth, or other polity, either native or naturalized, having certain rights, privileges, or duties.

Comment: They may not be citizens though. They could be PRs or even just visa holders.